# Conditional variable values in Azure DevOps build pipelines while using variable groups

Tags: azure-devops

I have been using the following variable settings to create some versioning in my projects which has worked fine.

```yaml
variables:
  major: 0
  minor: 0
  majorMinor: ${{variables.major}}.${{variables.minor}}

  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')}}:
    patch: $[counter(variables.majorMinor, 0)]
    branchTag:

  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')}}:
    patch: 0
    branchPatch: $[counter(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 0)]
    branchTag: -${{variables['build.sourcebranchname']}}.$(branchPatch)

  version: $(majorMinor).$(patch)
  semver: $(majorMinor).$(patch)$(branchTag)
```

Now I want to use variable groups to avoid having to specify shared variables across pipelines but I can't figure out how to define my conditional parameters when I have to define my variables with name/value.

```yaml
variables:
- group: nuget-credentials

- name: major
  value: 0
- name: minor
  value: 0
- name: majorMinor
  value: ${{variables.major}}.${{variables.minor}}

${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')}}:
  - name: patch
    value: $[counter(variables.majorMinor, 0)]
  - name: branchTag
    value:

${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')}}:
  - name: patch
    value: 0
  - name: branchPatch
    value: $[counter(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 0)]
  - name: branchTag
    value: -${{variables['build.sourcebranchname']}}.$(branchPatch)

- name: version
  value: $(majorMinor).$(patch)
- name: semver
  value: $(majorMinor).$(patch)$(branchTag)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using something like GitVersion to automatically drive version numbers rather than trying to roll your own implementation.

Comment: when you're using conditional expressions for list elements, conditions have to be list elements as well - should be `- ${{ if ... }}` (start with a hyphen).

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann I will look into using something like that tool instead. And qbik, that did solve that my original issue. I've updated the question with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from qbik's comment.

```yaml
variables:
- group: nuget-credentials
- name: 'major'
  value: 1
- name: 'minor'
  value: 0
- name: 'majorMinor'
  value: ${{variables.major}}.${{variables.minor}}
- name: 'patch'
  value: $[counter(variables.majorMinor, 0)]
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')}}:
  - name: 'patch'
    value: $[counter(variables.majorMinor, 0)]
  - name: 'branchTag'
    value:
- ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')}}:
  - name: 'patch'
    value: 0
  - name: 'branchPatch'
    value: $[counter(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 0)]
  - name: 'branchTag'
    value: -${{variables['build.sourcebranchname']}}.$(branchPatch)
- name: 'version'
  value: '$(majorMinor).$(patch)'
- name: 'semver'
  value: '$(majorMinor).$(patch)$(branchTag)'
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of question asker.*</sub>